# Run bash commands in parallel using iPython

Tags: bash, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

I'm using iPython notebook on a 16 core machine (so there are 15 "engines").  If I run this cell ...

```
%%px
%%bash
echo 'hi' > file1.txt
```

... then the result is one file called file1.txt that is written to disk 15 times.  What I really want is to write to 15 different files, file1.txt through file15.txt.

I'm new to all this, so I imagine there's a simple solution!

Thanks,

Retsreg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bash special variable `$$` is the PID of the shell, so you could do this:

```
echo hi > file$$.txt
```

That will write files like `file3392.txt` etc., where the number is the PID of each session.  You can later rename the files if you need to.

Comment: Comfirmed that this works, many thanks! Is there a similar way to get the date and time in the filename too?

Comment: You can try `file$$_$(date +%F_%T).txt`.  The `$()` evaluates its argument as a command and captures the output string, and you can use whatever format you want in the `date` command (I chose a standard one).